# (Swift.LazyMapCollection<Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>(_base:[ ]

Tags: string, swift, nsdictionary

The code says that it is perfectly fine and that there are no errors, but when I go to run the simulator, the words will include:

> (Swift.LazyMapCollection < Swift.Dictionary < Swift.String, Swift.String > (_base:[ ]

I am trying to create a quote app that displays a quote.

[image: This is the screenshot with the simulator]

Here is the code for the Import of the Plist:

```
import Foundation

struct ImportList {
let path: String

init(FileName: String) {
    self.path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(FileName)", ofType:"plist")!
}

var dict: Dictionary<String, String> {
    return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)! as! Dictionary
}

var array: Array<AnyObject> {
    return [String](arrayLiteral: String(dict.keys) { $0 as String})
}

func count() -> Int {
    return array.count
}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `arrayLiteral` in this case, just use `Array()`:

```
var array: Array<AnyObject> {
    return Array(dict.keys)
}
```

It safely converts the lazy collection to an actual array.

Comment: Thank you! Solved it immediately!